# Select model data using rails console and Apartment (Rails Multitenancy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a multitenancy base app using Apartment for Rails. Now i'm having trouble understanding how to access my data through the rails console.

Here is how the app might work : You sign up, it redirects you to your subdomain. When signing in, you have access to the app. You can create a company. The company can have many clients. Clients belongs to company. Company belongs to user. From here, everything works fine. The thing i'm trying to understand is how can i access my created data through the rails console? My app works fine, my data is still here after sign out/sign in.

Right now, i select my user using `user = User.first`. It returns my user. Now when i use `user.companies` it returns the following :

```
Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

And when using `user.clients`, it returns the following :

```
Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I'm still learning rails and it's the first time i try to create a multi-tenant app, so i might be missing something!

Here are my models :

```
// client.rb

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

```
// company.rb

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :clients

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients, allow_destroy: true

  scope :sorted, -> { order('position ASC') }
  scope :newest_first, -> { order('created_at ASC') }
  scope :search, ->(query) { where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]) }
end
```

```
// user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_tenant
  after_destroy :delete_tenant

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, request_keys: [:subdomain]

  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  # Contacts
  has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy

  def create_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.create(subdomain)
  end

  def delete_tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.drop(subdomain)
  end

  def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
    where(email: warden_conditions[:email], subdomain: warden_conditions[:subdomain]).first
 end
end
```

And here is my schema.rb

```
// schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_06_151658) do

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_clients_on_company_id"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.index ["client_id"], name: "index_companies_on_client_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "subdomain"
    t.index ["email", "subdomain"], name: "index_users_on_email_and_subdomain", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "companies", "clients"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a tenant's data from the console you have to switch to that tenant first, i.e.

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name')
# or 
Apartment::Tenant.switch!(user.subdomain)
```

To return to the default tenant, you type

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch # no arguments
```

See "[Switching Tenants](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switching-tenants)" for more information.

Comment: Words perfectly, i didn't understand the use of switch first but now... it makes sens! Thanks a lot!